# Failed to query elasticsearch for previous event in logstash

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch

Im very new logstash and created the config file to processing two different kind of file. I've Created field for similar in which are fields same in the input file and i have correlate some of the value from request to response. while in this scenario im facing following error, but in the query section which im parsing datat is similar only even though why it shown error im in clueless.Im storing both file in same index. If i run the file without deleting the index mean it will get correlate.

```
My correlation :
"

    elasticsearch {
                sort => [
                  {                
                    "partOrder.OrderRefNo"  => {"order" => "asc" "ignore_unmapped" => true}
                    "dlr.dlrCode"  => {"order" => "asc" "ignore_unmapped" => true}
                  }
                  ]
                  query => "type:transmit_req AND partOrder.OrderRefNo : %{partOrder.OrderRefNo} AND dlr.dlrCode : %{dlr.dlrCode}" 
                  fields => [
                            "partOrder.totalLineNo", "partOrder.totalLineNo",                       
                            "partOrder.totalOrderQty", "partOrder.totalOrderQty",
                            "partOrder.transportMethodType","partOrder.transportMethodType",
                            "dlr.brand","dlr.brand",
                            "partOrder.orderType","partOrder.orderType",
                            "partOrder.bodId","partOrder.bodId"
                            ]
                  fail_on_error => "false"
                }

"
```

Error:
    "
    ←[33mFailed to query elasticsearch for previous event {:query=>"type:transmit_re
    q AND partOrder.OrderRefNo : BC728010 AND dlr.dlrCode : 28012", :event=>#
    , @metrics={}, @channel=#>, @subscriber_lock=#, @level=:warn, @subscribers={2002=>#